# building the same file for different targets with different options

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, gnu-make

I have one "helper" file included in two "main" files which are built into two executables with the same makefile. I have debug print statements in the helper file. I want the print statements to actually be printed in one executable, but not the other. Is there a way to do it? Right now I have the following, and I was hoping to compile with DEBUG_PRINT defined for one executable but not the other, but I don't see how.

main1.cpp:

    `#include "helper.h"
    ...`

main2.cpp:

    `#include "helper.h"
    ...`

helper.cpp:

    `#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
    cout << "here is a debug message" << endl;
    #endif`

Makefile:

    `build: main1 main2
    main1: main1.o helper.o
        g++ -g -o main1 main1.o helper.o
    main2: main2.o helper.o
        g++ -g -o main2 main2.o helper.o
    %.o: %.cpp
        gcc -g -c $<`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need two different object files (main1-helper.o and main2-helper.o) and target-specific compiler flags:

```
 main1: CXXFLAGS=-DDEBUG_PRINT
 %.o: %.cpp
      gcc $(CXXFLAGS) -g -o $@ -c $<
```

Note: This leaves you with the problem of generating main1-helper.o from helper.o. There are a few ways to solve this; however, you might be more comfortable using automake from the start instead of rolling your own solutions.

Comment: +1 I misread the Makefile at first. There's no way around having two different object files aside from moving `$(CXXFLAGS) helper.cpp` to the `g++` link command (which seems kind of dirty).